# KendoUI MVVM Grid Page Events

Tags: html, grid, pagination, kendo-ui

I am developing a MVVM application and I am using KendoUI Grid. In the grid I want to get the onChange event when user change the pages. (I have been able to do this without MVVM). To do this, I have used the following element.

```
data-pageable='{ "pageSize": 2, events: {change: onPage}}' //This is not working
```

I want to the program to execute the onPage function when user changes the pages.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the grids Databound event which fires when a user changes the page. From there I am selecting the first row so it is highlighted. Hope this helps

In the grid definition:

```
.Events(events=>events.DataBound("Grid_Databound"))
```

In the script:

```
<script>
function Grid_Databound() {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        row = grid.tbody.find(">tr:not(.k-grouping-row)").eq(0);
        grid.select(row);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "events : { }", just "change", and you need to reference your view model:

```
data-pageable='{ pageSize: 2, change: yourviewmodel.onPage }'
```